Why is Firefox 125 25% faster?
I opened Firefox today to find it had automatically updated to Firefox 125.0.1 and was displaying this splash screen:

However even when I click through to the release notes, it's not immediately obvious what change(s) were responsible for this huge increase, or how the 25% metric was measured.

Considering that the "Test your speed" link takes you to https://browserbench.org/Speedometer3.0/ I would assume that it runs that test suite 25% faster. Most likely the javascript engine has had some optimisations.

At the bottom of the Release Notes there's a link that takes you to the full list of changes in the Firefox bug tracker, and this is the closest possible candidate I can find there, but I don't know the Firefox codebase well enough to know whether this would result in every page load being 25% faster.

Your link relates to some inefficiency in the JavaScript engine that was multiplying thousand-times one Web API request. Note that FF is only faster relatively to itself and relatively also to just one test-suite. Most likely they fixed some JavaScript bottlenecks, but this still doesn't make it the fastest browser around. But it was good for some commercial hype.

@harrymc Neither they nor I in the question claimed it to be "the fastest browser around". What according to you is the fastest browser, and based on which benchmarks?

One must ask, "faster by what metric?" Since there are many metrics Mozilla can use the question becomes a matter of opinion as to whether that chosen is menaingful in actual use.

@DrMoishePippik Exactly. In the case of the Firefox claim the metric given is the average page load time, I'm not sure what metric harrymc was thinking of when he brought up the topic of the fastest browser, or why he felt it was worth a downvote.

(I didn't downvote.) I don't believe in benchmarks - some products are optimized heavily to be the fastest in one important benchmark but not in general. You see this all the time in many areas. In the case of web access to the same target, all browsers should have the same speed, except for implementation deficiencies in their HTML/JavaScript engines. The relative speeds may change for another target.
